i want to apply antd layout to all component
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CreateEvent from "./CreateEvent"; // EventPage.js 파일을 가져옵니다.
import EventPage from "./EventPage"; // EventPage.js 파일을 가져옵니다.
import TimeTest from "./TimeTest";
import NoMatch from "./CreateEvent"; // NoMatch 컴포넌트를 가져옵니다.
import {
  UserOutlined,
  ExperimentOutlined,
  CheckCircleOutlined
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import MoHeader from "./Components/MoHeader";
import MoFooter from "./Components/MoFooter";

const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;

const App = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(false);

  const onCollapse = (collapsed) => {
    setCollapsed(collapsed);
  };

  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <Header>
        <MoHeader/>
      </Header>

      <Layout>
        <Sider
          collapsible
          collapsed={collapsed}
          onCollapse={onCollapse}
          style={{ overflow: 'auto', height: '100vh', position: 'fixed', left: 0, zIndex: 1 }}
        >
          <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline">
            <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
              <Link exact to="/" />
              Profile
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<ExperimentOutlined />}>
              <Link exact to="/test" />
              Experience
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<CheckCircleOutlined />}>
              <Link exact to="/time" />
              Skill
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>

        <Layout className="site-layout" style={{ marginLeft: collapsed ? 80 : 200 }}>
          <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px 0', overflow: 'initial' }}>
            <div className="app">
              <Routes> 
                <Route path="/" element={<CreateEvent />} />
                <Route path="/test" element={<EventPage />} />
                <Route path="/test/:uuid" element={<EventPage />} />
                <Route path="/time" element={TimeTest} />
                <Route path="/*" element={<NoMatch />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>
          </Content>

          <Footer>
            <MoFooter/>
          </Footer>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;

I made my app.js like this to apply antd layout. The main screen (createEvent) works fine, but when I press the menu to enter another site, the layout is not applied.
Is there any way to apply a common layout to all components?
I wanted the layout to stay the same when I pressed the button on the menu, but only the component came up.

What "layout" are you referring to in your code? Please [edit] to clarify the exact specific problem and provide more complete details.

Have you tried to use an 'Outlet' component you can easily wrap the children routes with any Layout you want..

There are no nested routes, Outlet would be completely useless here.
